# Box2d processing

Tags: java, processing, box2d

I'm new to processing and I'm getting an error while playing with Daniel Shiffman Box2D library. I'm trying to create a chain shape with vectors that I've defined in the main program. Since i need to create multiple surfaces , i made a Vec2 [x][y] x for the objects and y for the Vec2 points to create the chain but I keep coming with the "Type mismatch "main.Surface" does not match with "processing.core.PSurface"

Here is my entire code:

```
class Surface {
      ArrayList<Vec2> surface;
      int id;


      Surface(int id_, int largo, Vec2 [] r) {
        id=id_;

        surface = new ArrayList<Vec2>(largo);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < largo ; i++){
          surface.add(new Vec2(r[i]));
        }

        ChainShape chain = new ChainShape();

        Vec2[] vertices = new Vec2[surface.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
          vertices[i] = box2d.coordPixelsToWorld(surface.get(i));
        }

        chain.createChain(vertices, vertices.length);

        BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
        Body body = box2d.world.createBody(bd);
        body.createFixture(chain, 1);
      }

    }

    import shiffman.box2d.*;
    import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.*;
    import org.jbox2d.common.*;
    import org.jbox2d.dynamics.*;
    PImage background;

    Box2DProcessing box2d;

    Vec2[][] base;


    void setup() {
      fullScreen();
      //size(1600,900);
      background = loadImage("background.png");

      box2d = new Box2DProcessing(this);
      box2d.createWorld();

      ///////////////////////////////////////
          //Platforms positions vectors
      ///////////////////////////////////////

      base[0][0] = new Vec2(0 , 890.15);
      base[0][1] = new Vec2(85.933 , 890.15);
      base[0][2] = new Vec2(102.54 , 879.727);
      base[0][3] = new Vec2(126.003 , 879.727);
      base[0][4] = new Vec2(132.67 , 872.661);
      base[0][5] = new Vec2(189.729 , 872.661);
      base[0][6] = new Vec2(196.395 , 880.048);
      base[0][7] = new Vec2(228.898 , 880.048);
      base[0][8] = new Vec2(254.74 , 863.668);
      base[0][9] = new Vec2(283.438 , 863.668);
      base[0][10] = new Vec2(286.771 , 867.001);

      base[1][0] = new Vec2 (319.063 , 850.122);
      base[1][1] = new Vec2 (375.73 , 850.122);

      base[2][0] = new Vec2 (409.408 , 818.401);
      base[2][1] = new Vec2 (416.298 , 811.511);
      base[2][2] = new Vec2 (468.999 , 811.511);
      base[2][3] = new Vec2 (493.691 , 833.396);
      base[2][4] = new Vec2 (540.313 , 833.396);

      base[3][0] = new Vec2 (576.493 , 788.066);
      base[3][1] = new Vec2 (646.003 , 788.066);

      base[4][0] = new Vec2 (685.219 , 746.4);
      base[4][1] = new Vec2 (746.885 , 746.4);

      base[5][0] = new Vec2 (528.993 , 709.684);
      base[5][1] = new Vec2 (652.474 , 709.684);

      base[6][0] = new Vec2 (600.219 , 657.233);
      base[6][1] = new Vec2 (663.993 , 657.233);
      base[6][2] = new Vec2 (688.16 , 628.066);
      base[6][3] = new Vec2 (723.16 , 628.066);

      base[7][0] = new Vec2 (767.327 , 664.733);
      base[7][1] = new Vec2 (894.827 , 664.733);

      base[8][0] = new Vec2 (886.836 , 616.547);
      base[8][1] = new Vec2 (942.807 , 616.547);

      base[9][0] = new Vec2 (923.993 , 581.4);
      base[9][1] = new Vec2 (969.827 , 581.4);

      base[10][0] = new Vec2 (716.052 , 531.4);
      base[10][1] = new Vec2 (769.385 , 531.4);
      base[10][2] = new Vec2 (795.219 , 555.566);
      base[10][3] = new Vec2 (866.052 , 555.566);

      base[11][0] = new Vec2 (525.104 , 500.566);
      base[11][1] = new Vec2 (666.215 , 500.566);

      base[12][0] = new Vec2 (347.882 , 487.233);
      base[12][1] = new Vec2 (395.104 , 487.233);
      base[12][2] = new Vec2 (422.882 , 507.233);
      base[12][3] = new Vec2 (471.771 , 507.233);

      base[13][0] = new Vec2 (235.104 , 510.566);
      base[13][1] = new Vec2 (306.215 , 510.566);

      base[14][0] = new Vec2 (75.66 , 472.789);
      base[14][1] = new Vec2 (198.993 , 472.789);

      base[15][0] = new Vec2 (115.66 , 436.122);
      base[15][1] = new Vec2 (181.771 , 436.122);
      base[15][2] = new Vec2 (209.271 , 408.622);
      base[15][3] = new Vec2 (243.993 , 408.622);
      base[15][4] = new Vec2 (273.021 , 379.594);
      base[15][5] = new Vec2 (316.215 , 379.594);
      base[15][6] = new Vec2 (333.021 , 362.789);
      base[15][7] = new Vec2 (377.327 , 362.789);

      base[16][0] = new Vec2 (98.944 , 307.233);
      base[16][1] = new Vec2 (153.993 , 307.233);
      base[16][2] = new Vec2 (181.215 , 325.37);
      base[16][3] = new Vec2 (247.882 , 325.37);
      base[16][4] = new Vec2 (286.771 , 337.789);
      base[16][5] = new Vec2 (320.66 , 337.789);

      base[17][0] = new Vec2 (33.16 , 236.678);
      base[17][1] = new Vec2 (60.938 , 236.678);
      base[17][2] = new Vec2 (78.16 , 258.066);
      base[17][3] = new Vec2 (102.049 , 258.066);

      base[18][0] = new Vec2 (67.604 , 208.066);
      base[18][1] = new Vec2 (98.944 , 208.066);
      base[18][2] = new Vec2 (113.715 , 193.017);
      base[18][3] = new Vec2 (136.215 , 193.017);

      base[19][0] = new Vec2 (175.104 , 193.017);
      base[19][1] = new Vec2 (205.66 , 193.017);
      base[19][2] = new Vec2 (222.604 , 177.789);
      base[19][3] = new Vec2 (247.604 , 177.789);

      base[20][0] = new Vec2 (320.66 , 177.789);
      base[20][1] = new Vec2 (568.993 , 177.789);

      base[21][0] = new Vec2 (606.787 , 220.959);
      base[21][1] = new Vec2 (685.219 , 220.959);

      base[22][0] = new Vec2 (767.327 , 337.789);
      base[22][1] = new Vec2 (875.415 , 337.789);

      base[23][0] = new Vec2 (900.66 , 301.4);
      base[23][1] = new Vec2 (1049.827  , 301.4);
      base[23][2] = new Vec2 (1084.688 , 336.261);
      base[23][3] = new Vec2 (1118.16 , 336.261);

      base[24][0] = new Vec2 (1158.16 , 458.066);
      base[24][1] = new Vec2 (1290.66 , 458.066);

      base[25][0] = new Vec2 (1374.827 , 573.066);
      base[25][1] = new Vec2 (1599.827 , 573.066);
      //////////////////////////////////////////

      for(int i = 0 ; i < base.length ; i++){
        surface = new Surface (i, base[i].length , base[i]) ;
      }

    }

    void draw() {
      box2d.step();
      imageMode(CENTER);
      image(background,width/2,height/2,1600,900);
    }

    ///////////////end/////////////
```

So, the problem that i'm getting is between line 6 and 169. The problem is when I try to send to the Surface constructor (which is supposed to receive a Vec2 [] r) the base[i] from void setup(){}

I would really appreciate any help!!! The error I believe that comes from the constructor in the class Surface and the list type that I'm trying to push to the constructor when i create a new surface. This is for a homework at college and I'm a bit against the clock, so any help would be REALLY useful!!!

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

Processing 3 added a `surface` variable of type [`PSurface`](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PSurface.java).

You shouldn't have your own variable named `surface` because it conflicts with the existing `surface` variable.

To fix the first error, just change the name of your `surface` variables to something else.

After you do that, you have another problem: you never initialize a `surface` variable at the sketch level. But that will become more obvious when you change the variable name.